# Bind values of one ViewModel with another ViweModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have TabViewModel which contains TabControl and another ViewModel(productViewmodel).
Based on selection of Tab i pass values to productviewmodel(programitically) so that respective values gets displayed

Is there a way we can bind the values in TabViewmodel directly to values of productViewmodel without programitically passing it.

i hope this explains

thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using MVVM light then look for Messenger Class of it.You can send any object from one viewmodel to another in message. This way you can communicate betweem VMs.

Comment: Does the TabViewModel have an instance of the ProductViewModel?

Comment: Loop I need to look at messanger classes. And tabviewmodel do have instance of productviewmodel.thanks